# jquery plugin for floating a div like in gmail

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a plugin that does the following:

When the user scrolls the page, and a div element is about to be scrolled out of the viewport, this div is floated via `position:fixed` and remains in the same spot it was before being scrolled out of the viewport while the user scrolls.

You can see an example of this behavior in gmail for example.

There is a number of corner-cases that must be dealt with properly:

- the original content does not 'bounce' around when the element is floated
- the element that is floated looks the same way it did before being floated
- when user scrolls horizontally, the element remains in the correct location
- if the element is wider then the viewport, sane things happen when its floated
- it looks smooth in IE7+, Chrome and FF

My coworker [implemented 80% of these requirements](https://github.com/Glench/jquery.floatScroll), but the last 20% is proving difficult. Can someone recommend a plugin that does this already?

Comment: most of your issues lie in CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: i agree. javascript needs to properly set css so that things look good

Comment: no, JavaScript needs to properly toggle a class like `.scrolling` or something, and the rest can be done from CSS using the right selectors.

Comment: no it cant be. this need to be able to work for "any" element, this means that i cant write css generic enough to solve my 5 bullet points. There are too many edge cases, you cant encompass them all into a style

Comment: take a look at jQuery UI. Much of it expects content to be formatted in a particular manner for it to work with the plugins. There's no reason you can't expect the same for a floating header. Most of your "corner-cases" are just symptoms of poorly written CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt a plugin exists because the code is actually quite simple. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HB4bR/

And the JS:

```
var fixMe = $('.fixMe');
var initPos = fixMe.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrl > initPos){
        fixMe.css({position:'fixed', top:0, left:0});
    }else{
        fixMe.css('position','static');
    }
});
```

We simply grab the initial position of `.fixMe` relative to the page at the start. Then, as the user scrolls, we get the scroll position (`scrl`) and check it against the `initPos` of `.fixMe`. If the scroll position is greater, `.fixMe` gets a fixed position. Otherwise, it gets a static position (this is to restore it to it's original place once you scroll back up).

**Update**
mkoryak pointed out some problems with the above implementation. Here's an example that addresses those issues: http://jsfiddle.net/HB4bR/8/

And the updated code:

```
var fixMe = $('.fixMe');
var fixMeSpacer = fixMe.next();
var initPos = fixMe.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrl > initPos){
        fixMe.css({position:'fixed', top:0});
        fixMeSpacer.show();
    }else{
        fixMe.css('position','relative');
        fixMeSpacer.hide();
    }
});
```

There are really just two changes here. I've created a hidden "spacer" element (`fixMeSpacer`) that has the same width and height of `fixMe`. When `fixMe` gets a fixed position, this spacer is shown in order to preserve the location of content below. It's then hidden again once `fixMe` gets popped back into place.

The other change was simply to remove the `left` property from the `.css()` call.

Comment: yes i thought it was quite simple first too. but it is not. for example, in your code the element is moved to 0,0 which is probably not its location on the screen. also, as the element is set to `fixed` it is yanked out of the dom layout, and things move into its place possibly breaking your layout.

Comment: take a look at your update fiddle with some more "real world" html. as you can see, it breaks down pretty rapidly. http://jsfiddle.net/HB4bR/7/

Comment: I've made some simple updates to the code that addresses those issues. Take a look.